# Identityserver4 1.0.0-rc1-update2 ended up with 1.0.0-beta1-update1

Tags: identityserver4

i would like to update my project to use 1.0.0-rc1-update2 but in my project.json it says i ended up with 1.0.0-beta1-update1. What am i doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you upgrade net core sdk and use rtm packages instead of rc1?

Comment: @ademcaglin's comment alludes to the answer. The dependencies of rc1-update2 are all the RTM packages. So your project and rc1-update2 wont work together.

Comment: Ah of course thank you i never updated the sdk. Ill update and updat the question/ select the answer

Answer (score 0):

@adem caglin Thanks i never updated my sdk and like @Lutando said i should update the rest of the packages too